# HTTP Basic Auth using HttpURLConnection - Fails the first time

Tags: java, tomcat, basic-authentication, netweaver

I am completely lost. I try to authenticate using HTTP Basic Auth to a Tomcat 7.0.54 to get a resource.

The first time of a day that I try to connect I get a 401. The rest of the day I will get the resource. Even if I restart the Tomcat, I will get the resource with the first request. I can not restart the client...

I have the following code:

```
URL urlObject = new URL(url);
String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userPassword.getBytes());
 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
 
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
 
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
 
String postParameters = "X='xyz'";
connection.setDoOutput(true);

connection.connect();
DataOutputStream outputStreamToConnection = new DataOutputStream(
connection.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStreamToConnection, "ISO-8859-1"));
writer.write(postParameters);
writer.close();
outputStreamToConnection.flush();
outputStreamToConnection.close();

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Anyone any idea what causes the first reject of the Tomcat? I logged my header-requests and the headers are the same for first and second request...

It looks like the client would cache something. It is running on an SAP AS Java server. Hope anybody experienced the same problem. :)
Thanks
Ben

Comment: Maybe there is a problem on the Tomcat side?

Comment: I thought so as well, but wouldn’t the restart of the Tomcat let the problem occur after the first request to the Tomcat after the restart?
But if you could point me into a direction, I would gladly look into it.

Comment: Do your requests contain some sort of cookies?

Comment: @user3513092 regarding restart: Does your tomcate dispose session infos on restart?

Comment: No cookies; which flag need to be set to dispose the session infos?

Comment: see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html - it is the saveOnRestart attribute. It defaults to true. You may try to set it to false. How do you configure the basic auth at tomcat?

Comment: You were right. It is the tomcat. Even a request with Postman or Soap Ui are failing, if they are sending the first request of the day. I have to check, why Tomcat is behaving like this :-/

Comment: Just wanted to add, we never figured out why the first call of the day failed. We just add a retry into the software to try it twice